# Custom entity migration policy (NSEntityMigrationPolicy subclass) methods not called during migration (iOS 5 only)

Tags: ios, core-data, core-data-migration

I'm doing a custom migration as lightweight migration doesn't allow me to mess with each entity as it is migrated (which I need to do).  However, I am still inferring a mapping model.

```
NSMappingModel *mappingModel = [NSMappingModel inferredMappingModelForSourceModel:sourceModel destinationModel:destinationModel error:&error];
```

Then, I add my custom migration policy to each entity mapping:

```
NSArray * newEntityMappings = [NSArray arrayWithArray:mappingModel.entityMappings];

for (NSEntityMapping * entityMapping in newEntityMappings) {
    entityMapping.entityMigrationPolicyClassName = NSStringFromClass([MyCustomEntityMigrationPolicy class]);
}

mappingModel.entityMappings = newEntityMappings;
```

Now, in iOS 4.0, 4.1, 4.2 and 4.3 this works fine and for each entity I get a chance to change its property values when the `createDestinationInstancesForSourceInstance:entityMapping:manager:error:` method of MyCustomEntityMigrationPolicy is called.

However, in iOS 5.0 and 5.1, no instance of MyCustomEntityMigrationPolicy is ever instantiated.

Is this a bug in iOS 5 or am I doing something wrong?